# How to solve 'keyWindow' was depreciated in iOS 13 (AutoLayout)

Tags: swift, autolayout, ios13

I am changing that safe area height using key window, this VC presents modally over another VC and keyWindow was depreciated. How can I solve this?

```
 // set the new top constraint value for card view
        // card view won't move down just yet, we need to call layoutIfNeeded()
        // to tell the app to refresh the frame/position of card view
        if let safeAreaHeight = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.safeAreaLayoutGuide.layoutFrame.size.height,
          let bottomPadding = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.safeAreaInsets.bottom {
```

Comment: Why do you need to do this with the key window? Why not base things on the safe area of the view controller's view?

Comment: Why are you accessing the key window? You are creating a window in your application delegate and you can use that. However, using safe area in the controller would be much better.

Comment: I am new to iOS Dev and thought this would be the proper way, How can I just use the safe area